# How to update Azure functions from .netcore 3.x to .net 5.0

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-5, azure-functions-core-tools

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#v2

1. Installed Azure Functions Core Tools x86 (3.0.3331)
2. Installed Azure Functions Core Tools x64 (3.0.3331)
3. Added Environment Variables to Path
4. Update net core 3.1.x, net 5.0.x

Unfortunately i get this result:
`func --version 2.7.1948`

What else?

Answer (score 0):

After some time I found the helpful command `where` in cmd.

```
where func
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\func.exe 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\func.exe 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\func.exe
```

Surprising that Visual Studio 2019 uses **chocolately** when installing azure function-core tools.

This command resolves the problem:

`choco upgrade all`

Yeah:

`func --version 3.0.3331`